# Why sonar metrics are sometimes wrong?

Tags: c++, sonarqube, metrics, sonarqube-4.5

My sonar metrics are sometimes wrong on :

- *number of comments*
- *number of classes*
- *number of lines*
- *number of code lines*

For example, when I click on the metric number of classes, I see some files with correct count number of classes, **but I see some files with all metrics with a 0 value**.

What is wrong ?

(May there be a memory limit, or a file count limit ?...)

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the problem? If the problematic files are the only ones to process, does the issue still occur?

Comment: Are you using the community C++ plugin or the commercial one?

Comment: No I didn't, I will try this one. @Mithfindel : I'm using the community C++ plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an isolation of the specific problematic files, I found **parsing errors** :

*com.sonar.sslr.api.RecognitionException: Parse error at line 123 column 0 failed to match all of: parametersAndQualifiers virtSpecifier ctorInitializer compoundStatement functionTryBlock parametersAndQualifiers bracedInitList*

It appears **sonar does not support some boost instructions** like this one :

```
BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(MyClass, 0)
```

So next step, find a workaround...

Comment: A first workaround is to add the property `sonar.cxx.errorRecoveryEnabled=true` to continue parsing of the entire file.